# receiving collection element of type int is not an objective c object in iOS

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
NSDictionary* jsonDict = @{
                               @"firstName": txtFirstName.text,
                               @"lastName": txtLastName.text,
                               @"email": txtEmailAddress.text,
                               @"password": txtPassword.text,
                               @"imageUrl": imageUrl,
                               @"facebookId": [fbId integerValue],
                              };
```

In the last element, I need to use an integer, but I am receiving the error:

```
collection element of type int is not an objective c object
```

How can I use an int value in this element?

Comment: `@"facebookId" : [fbId integerValue]` should be `@"facebookId" : @([fbId longLongValue])`. In Swift however, there is no cast requirement for numbers: i.e. `let jsonDict = [..., "facebookId" : fbId.longLongValue() ]`

Answer (score 70, accepted):

should be:

```
@"facebookId": [NSNumber numberWithInt:[fbId intValue]];
```

`NSDictionary` works with objects only and as a result, we can't store simply `int`s or `integer`s or `bool`s or anyother *primitive* datatypes.

`[fbId integerValue]` returns a primitive integer value (*which is not an object*)
Hence we need to encapsulate *primitive* datatypes and make them into objects. which is why we need to use a class like `NSNumber` to make an object to simply store this crap.

more reading: http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/nsnumber.html

Answer (score 8):

assuming **fbID** is an `int` then It should be like:

```
@"facebookId": @(fbId)
```

Answer (score 6):

OR, assuming fbID is an `NSString`,

```
@"facebookId": @([fbId intValue]);
```

its like autoboxing in Java. @ converts any primitive number to NSNumber object.

Comment: And if `fbId` is already an `NSNumber` then it should be `@"facebookId" : fbId,` It's unclear whether it's an `NSString` or `NSNumber` since both have the `integerValue` method.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use @(%value%) for non pointer datatype value store in Dictionary.

```
@"facebookId": @(fbId)
```

Answer (score 1):

NSDictionary can only hold objects (e.g. NSString, NSNumber, NSArray, etc.), not primitive values (e.g. int, float, double, etc.). The same goes for almost all encapsulation in Objective-C. To store numbers, use NSNumber:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"key" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:integerValue]]};
```

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using an `NSNumber`:

```
NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    NSNumber * myNumber = [f numberFromString:fbId];
    [f release];
```

Comment: Why did you need to take such a convoluted approach to parse a BigInt like a Facebook Id? It's only a 64-bit integer/20 character string. You can easily just do `[fbId longLongValue]` to parse the string into a primitive number and then `@([fbId longLongValue])` to cast it as an `NSNumber`